# Shell : How to work on commands which are returning null?

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script which ll auto start django server after linux boots.

While wrting i faced a issue is like:

I am executing a command:  `exec python manage.py makemigrations`
This commands returns no changes detected. After that my script is terminated

After this command i want to execute some more commands.
Can some1 give some idea?

Comment: `exec` _replaces_ the shell script process with the Python process. Once that happens (assuming it can in fact execute the new command at all, meaning `PATH` lookup succeeds, and `python` is executable), the shell script execution is _gone_. Don't use `exec` if you might need to do something else in the shell script.

Comment: What do you mean by "null"?  Programs (on UNIXs) can only return an integer between 0 and 255.  Why are you using `exec`?  On the bash command-line, look at `help exec`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `exec`, I think you can just use `python manage.py makemigrations &`, add `&` to run the command at background.

Answer (score 0):

just use `python manage.py makemigrations`

`exec` will terminate the current shell and execute your command. After completion of the execution you will not get back to the current shell and lose the following commands, That is the reason your script gets terminated.

If the following commands are independent of each other then you can use `&` and the commands will start executing concurrently at the background otherwise no need of `&`.